# Is this code executing asynchronously?

Tags: node.js

I'm learning Node.js and I've come to understand the concept of asynchronous function calls. But now I have a new conundrum.

I have some code that looks like this (you don't have to read it in detail, it's just an excerpt to illustrate my question):

```
var seat_winner = states[gid].current_trick[trick_winner].seat;console.log(seat_winner+" won "+trick_pts+" points");
            states[gid][seat_winner].points += trick_pts;
            if(states[gid][seat_winner].team == "blue"){
                states[gid].points_blue += trick_pts;
                states[gid].points_blue_total += trick_pts;
            }
            else{
                states[gid].points_red += trick_pts;
                states[gid].points_red_total += trick_pts;
            }

            states[gid].current_trick = {
                1: {seat: 0, card: "N"},
                2: {seat: 0, card: "N"},
                3: {seat: 0, card: "N"},
                4: {seat: 0, card: "N"}
            };
            states[gid].trick_in_progress++;
            var score = [states[gid].points_blue, states[gid].points_red, states[gid].points_blue_total, states[gid].points_red_total, states[gid].game40holder, states[gid].trump];
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('score', score);

            //also tell the client to clean up the display for the next trick
            io.sockets.in(room).emit('cleanUp', null);

next++;
        if(next > 4)
            next -= 4;
        states[gid].next_to_play = next;
        states[gid].current_trick[order_to_play] = { "seat": seat, "card": states[gid][seat].hand[to_play] };
        states[gid].played_cards.push(states[gid][seat].hand[to_play]);
        states[gid][seat].hand[to_play] = "N";

        nextMove(gid);
```

There are no function calls here as I see, except for the `nextMove()` function at the very end. But I'm getting some strange results on the client, like the code above is executing asynchronously altogether. But that doesn't make sense, does it? Is there any reason at all for the above to execute asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see any callback functions specified in your code above.

Only thing in your code that code be creating problem for you is the following lines..

> > ```
> >        io.sockets.in(room).emit('score', score);
> >
> >        //also tell the client to clean up the display for the next trick
> >        io.sockets.in(room).emit('cleanUp', null);
> > ```

When the 1st emits happen, immediately after that, the 2nd emit takes place.. Maybe thats not what you want.. Probably you want to make a 2nd emit when 1st emit is complete!

Edit : So you can say the above lines of are asynchronous, since 2nd emit is fired even before the 1st one is fully completed.

Comment: The first and second emit are independent, so that's ok. I think the real problem is that the second emit is still executing on the client when the `nextMove` function is called - and that function has an emit of its own. If I understand the concept correctly, I could remedy this by placing `nextMove()` inside a callback function?

Comment: Yes that could be the problem, so you should call your `nextMove()` when the 2nd emit is complete. :)